# How can I swap a value on a line?

Tags: sed

If the value is `YES`, make it `NO`.  If it is `NO` make it `YES`.
I am using the following command as an example:

```
( echo "online=YES"; echo "online=NO" ) | sed -e 's/online=YES/online=NO/' -e 's/online=NO/online=YES/'

online=YES
online=YES
```

If the first pattern is matched, then it should skip the second pattern.  This would be the equivalent to the `next` in `awk`.

Comment: I need to use sed, I know I can do it in awk or perl

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -e 's/online=YES/online=NO/' -e t -e 's/online=NO/online=YES/'
```

The `t` command in `sed` will branch to the given label (or to the end of the `sed` script if no label is given) if a previous `s` command has made a substitution since the most recent reading of an input line.

In this case, it will bypass the second substitution if the first substitution was carried out.

---

For the case where there may be multiple `online=YES` or `online=NO` on a lines, use

```
sed -e 's/online=YES/online=MAYBE/g' \
    -e 's/online=NO/online=YES/g' \
    -e 's/online=MAYBE/online=NO/g'
```

where the string `MAYBE` is not otherwise associated with the `online=` pattern. This would be similar in nature of using a temporary variable to swap the values of two variables.

Testing:

```
$ echo "online=YES online=YES online=NO online=YES" | sed -e 's/online=YES/online=MAYBE/g' -e 's/online=NO/online=YES/g' -e 's/online=MAYBE/online=NO/g'
online=NO online=NO online=YES online=NO
```

---

The reason that the `n` command doesn't quite work in place of the `t` command in the first example is that this will read the next line of input halfway through the script and run the second half of the script on that line:

```
$ ( echo "online=YES"; echo "online=YES" ) | sed -e 's/online=YES/online=NO/' -e n -e 's/online=NO/online=YES/'
online=NO
online=YES
```

You'll get the same output for two `NO` lines.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  I had just discovered that doing the same thing you mentioned only with -e n also works.  Thanks!  As far as I know, they amount to the same thing - not sure.  I think the "n" says move to the next line, whereas "t" is branch to the label (none=next line) if there was a match?

Comment: @garylaxton That works for the given data, but try it with two `input=YES`...

Comment: @Kusalananda You don't need `PROBABLY`, change `NO` to `YES` directly after all `YES` have already been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `t` command as @Kusalananda pointed out, works for your example (and most others). To actually swap two strings in one replacement you can do something like

```
sed 'H;x;s/^/#NO#YES#NO/;s/.*#\(.*\)#\([^#]*\).*\n\(.*online=\)\1/\3\2/'
```

This can easily be expanded to three or more strings to rotate.

To process more lines, lines including more replacements or lines without replacements at all, you can expand it to loop over the replacement:

```
sed -e 'H;x;s/online=/&#/g;s/^/#NO#YES#NO#/;:a' -e 's/\(.*#\)\(.*\)#\([^#]*\)\(#.*\n\)\(.*online=\)#\2/\1\2#\3\4\5\3/;ta' -e 's/.*\n//'
```

Comment: Note that it assumes there's only one `online=(YES|NO)` per line.

Comment: Also the hold space ends up containing the current line after the first line. You'd need to do some cleanup or better insert that newline with a `s` command instead. Try on the output of `printf 'online=%s\n' NO YES`

Comment: Expanded for multi-line, multi-pattern

Comment: It's still not working on the output of `printf 'online=%s\n' NO YES`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, just tested some more complicated cases, but not this one. Tried to optimize more than possible. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Some `perl` techniques:

```
perl -pe 's/online=\K(YES|NO)/$1 eq "YES" ? "NO" : "YES"/ge'
perl -pe 's/online=\K(YES(?{$r = "NO"})|NO(?{$r = "YES"}))/$r/g'
```

See [this answer to a related question](/a/389538) for a generalisation of the approach in the second example.

Here, you could also use a hash to define a translation table to be applied to the word following `online=`:

```
 perl -pe 'BEGIN{%s = (YES => NO, NO => YES)}
           s{online=\K\w+}{$s{$&} // $&}ge'
```

A difference from the previous solutions is that it would not change `online=YES1` to `online=NO1` as it would check `YES` against `YES1` (matched by `\w+`).